# How to serialize complex IEnumerable class in protobuf?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a `RoaringBitmap` which represent billions of bits. It is bitmap which is faster/more compact version of `BitArray` and is unmanaged. It does implement IEnumerable, but more like extension to get positions, and I don't intend to copy their entire repo to fix implementation.
In compact form it takes about **100 bytes**, in extended through `IEnumerable` - **1 GB**.

I tried using converters with surrogates, but get exception:

```
public static class ProtobufSerializer
{
    [ProtoContract]
    public sealed class RoaringBitmapSurrogate
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }

        private const SerializationFormat Format = SerializationFormat.Portable;

        [ProtoConverter]
        public static RoaringBitmapSurrogate Convert(RoaringBitmap obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;
            return new RoaringBitmapSurrogate { Data = obj.Serialize(Format) };
        }
        [ProtoConverter]
        public static RoaringBitmap Convert(RoaringBitmapSurrogate obj)
        {
            if(obj == null)
                return null;
            return RoaringBitmap.Deserialize(obj.Data, Format);
        }
    }

    static ProtobufSerializer()
    {
        var model = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
        //model.Add(typeof(RoaringBitmapSurrogate), true);
        model.Add(typeof(RoaringBitmap), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(RoaringBitmapSurrogate));
    }


    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data)
    {
        return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(new MemoryStream(data));
    }
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException : For repeated data declared as
> CRoaring.RoaringBitmap, the *underlying* collection
> (CRoaring.RoaringBitmap) must implement ICollection and must not
> declare itself read-only; alternative (more exotic) collections can be
> used, but must be declared using their well-known form (for example, a
> member could be declared as ImmutableHashSet)

How to serialize it in **protobuf-net**? Obviously serializing `IEnumerable` is just stupid.
And Im concerned about logic behind `IEnumerable` serialization overall, because it potentially can be infinite, be a generator or simply too big (like in my case).

Comment: You beat me to it, but "ignore list handling" is the immediate thing here. However, I also wonder if this scenario would benefit from a true custom serializer. That is possible in v3, and would probably be a lot more efficient. Let me know if that something you want me to discuss more (I'm the library author), but: it is probably a bit too involved for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Wow, thx for response and tips on v3 =) I will definitely update when it comes out (if it is netstd2.1 compliant)

Comment: it came out 2 years ago, and support netstandard2.0 and netstandard2.1 among other TFMs

Comment: Oh, didn't looked at version, sry. Then how I should I do this? Is this something like IJsonConvert ?

Comment: Here's an example; consider `BlobLike` as your custom type that is sort of like a `byte[]` - the custom serializer has mechanisms to read/write the payload in whatever way you like, without adding an extra layer into the object model. There's also another way of doing this, with `IMemoryConverter<,>`, which might also be suitable: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/481614450935d903ea3a821f85a0c735

Comment: This is indeed looking better without surrogate payload. Thank you! I will update my answer as soon as I get from home =)

Comment: @MarcGravell Added my solution (didn't figure out how to use ReadOnlyMemory for writing, it throws error that it is readonly)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, just add this to model:

```
        var bmModel = model.Add(typeof(RoaringBitmap), false);
        bmModel.IgnoreListHandling = true;
        bmModel.SetSurrogate(typeof(RoaringBitmapSurrogate));
```

**Update**

Following @MarcGravell suggestion, I ended up with using ISerializer interface (it still complains about IEnumerable so I set the flag to ignore this behavior, but there is no surrogate class anymore):

```
public static class ProtobufSerializer
{
    private sealed class RoaringBitmapSerializer : ISerializer<RoaringBitmap>
    {
        private const int MaxRoaringBitmapSize = 8 * 1024;//suffice for my needs, but not yours.
        private static readonly ArrayPool<byte> Pool = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared;

        private const SerializationFormat Format = SerializationFormat.Portable;

        public RoaringBitmap Read(ref ProtoReader.State state, RoaringBitmap value)
        {
            var buffer = Pool.Rent(MaxRoaringBitmapSize);
            try
            {
                var read = state.ReadBytes(buffer);
                return RoaringBitmap.Deserialize(read.ToArray(), Format);
            }
            finally
            {
                Pool.Return(buffer);
            }
        }

        public void Write(ref ProtoWriter.State state, RoaringBitmap value)
        {
            state.WriteBytes(value.Serialize(Format));
        }

        public SerializerFeatures Features => SerializerFeatures.CategoryScalar | SerializerFeatures.WireTypeString;
    }

    static ProtobufSerializer()
    {
        var model = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
        var bmModel = model.Add(typeof(RoaringBitmap), false);
        bmModel.SerializerType = typeof(RoaringBitmapSerializer);
        bmModel.IgnoreListHandling = true;
    }


    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data)
    {
        return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(new MemoryStream(data));
    }
}
```